# Java: Parse output from ffmpeg

Tags: java, string, parsing, text

I am trying to parse some output from the `ffmpeg -i` command. Some of the output may look like this:

```
  libavutil     50. 8. 0 / 50. 8. 0
  libavcodec    52.52. 0 / 52.52. 0
  libavformat   52.50. 0 / 52.50. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0.10. 0 /  0.10. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, avi, from '/my/folder/clip.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:05:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 554 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: msvideo1, rgb555le, 160x100, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
```

How can I parse out the bitrate value on the second last line? I cannot make a static parser that just picks the value at position x in the String because the output differs from time to time, so I have to make it dynamic in some way.

But how?

Comment: Can you serch for string "bitrate" in the parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.
Try something like this :

```
String text = "Duration: 00:05:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 554 kb/s";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".?bitrate:\\s([0-9]*)\\skb/s");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

More on Java and regular expressions : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Simply search for the string "bitrate:" and go from there.